# Is the legacy portal at Apigee now considered dead?

Tags: apigee

I have been using Apigee for well over a year now and starting 05/11/2014 the "legacy portal" is no longer available.

I have reported the broken link on the new admin portal to allow a developer to use the friendlier "legacy portal", but was told it was a 'bug' and would be looked into going forward.

The new admin portal is NOT user friendly, does not provide the same easy layout and link structure AND if you have any base64 strings in any of your entities inside a collection, the new admin portal makes it impossible to inspect data in that entity conveniently.

The JSON whether formatted or not seems to STRETCH the 'details view' window, instead of maintaining a 'view window' like the "legacy portal" did, so when you execute "view details" on an entity with base64 it appears as though ALL other entities listed in the query results DISAPPEAR. And the 'Hide Details' link also disappears (you have to go to the bottom, scroll the window all the way to the right until you find the "hide details" links.  Then you have to go back to the top of the currently displayed details opened up for the selected entity to CLOSE and/or HIDE the details view).

What are you guys thinking over there at Apigee ... the "legacy portal" was very pleasant to use, well laid out, easy to navigate and presented data in a way that was easy to understand and more importantly to work with!!!

If it WORKS, don't FIX IT!

I would like to know how I can get access to the "legacy portal" again.  Someone please advise!

Answer (score 2):

We have made the legacy portal active again at http://apigee.com/appservices/archive/. Besides data explorer, which other areas of our portal do you use? We would love to get your feedback on those as well.

Comment: Thank you Prabhat.  In addition to 'data explorer' which allows me the convenience of applying data (as an UPDATE or an ADD) to existing entities globally while allowing me to conveniently verify changes in the application which effect data in the entities, I also frequently use the 'app overview' to get a quick glance at activity in my collections and I use the 'user management' area to alter user records as well.  The 'analytics' area is an area I frequently use, too.  The application I am building is currently just for mobile web, but we will soon be introducing a hybrid mobile app as well.

Comment: With respect to your analytics comment, if you are using our latest JS SDK you should be getting out of box performance metrics (log, api perf etc) on our new UI at https://apigee.com/appservices/#!/performance/api-perf . This is not available on legacy portal.

Comment: I have looked at your new api perf but prefer the legacy portal's analytics ... which are selectable and have much nicer graphing as well.

Answer (score 0):

The point of having both Legacy and Beta live at the same time is so we can report these things to the Apigee design team before the Legacy portal is retired. Getting feedback on how to make the new one work better is what it's all about -- but keeping two versions of the portal live forever opens a can of worms for support and bug tracking.

The new portal has been in testing since almost the beginning of the year so it was time to retire the old portal -- best thing to do now is to open individual questions on Stack Overflow or email feature requests to help@apigee.com. Your post here is too broad for SO members to respond to or for the Apigee team to create actionable tickets on.